# About assert enable

Tags: java, eclipse, assert

can any body tell me how can I enable assertion in eclipse Helios? I am using java 6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go to **Run > Run Configurations...**
2. Select your **Java Application**
3. Go to the **Arguments** tab
4. Add `-ea` to the your **VM arguments**

Answer (score 2):

See this article, [Don't Forget to enable Java assert](http://thesoftwarelife.blogspot.com/2008/05/dont-forget-to-enable-java-assert.html). And also see [this forum discussion](http://www.coderanch.com/t/416987/java/java/enable-Assertions-eclipse) about enable assertion.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable assertions for one particular execution, see WhiteFang34's answer.

I prefer having assertions enabled by default, so I do

1. Go to **Window -> Preferences**
2. Go to **Java -> Installed JREs**
3. Select the JRE and click **Edit**
4. Add `-ea` in the *Default VM arguments**-field